# Unable to upload a picture on firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload a picture on firebase storage. On pressing capture button for capturing picture my app crashes and i get this error:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

on this line `Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.faum.faum_expert.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);`

That is my code:

```
private ImageView ivKitchen1,ivKitchen2,ivKitchen3;
private Button btnCapture1,btnCapture2,btnCapture3;
private TextView tvKitchenSnaps;

private StorageReference snapsStorage;

private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

private ProgressDialog mProgress;

private Uri filepath;



String mCurrentPhotoPath;

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "com.faum.faum_expert.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.kitchen_snaps);

    snapsStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();


    ivKitchen1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivKitchen1);

    btnCapture1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCapture1);

    mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);

    btnCapture1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);*/

            dispatchTakePictureIntent();
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        mProgress.setMessage("Uploading...");
        mProgress.show();
        Uri uri = data.getData();

        StorageReference filepath = snapsStorage.child("Photos").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
        filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Toast.makeText(Kitchen_Snaps.this, "Upload Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mProgress.dismiss();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(Kitchen_Snaps.this, "Upload Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Manifesto File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<!--
-
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.faum.faum_expert.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
</provider>
-->
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Social_Connect" />
    <activity android:name=".User_sign" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <activity android:name=".Personal_Information" />
    <activity android:name=".Contact_Infrormation" />
    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" />
    <activity android:name=".Kitchen_Snaps" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Navigation_Drawer"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_navigation__drawer"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity android:name=".New_Deal" />
    <activity android:name=".New_Deal_Time" />
    <activity android:name=".New_Deal_List" />
    <activity android:name=".New_Deal_Confirmation"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: post your Manifest too

Comment: I posted manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have to check permission at first
I hope it helps
Here are full source code

```
public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 123;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.kitchen_snaps);

    snapsStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();


    ivKitchen1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivKitchen1);

    btnCapture1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCapture1);

    mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);

    btnCapture1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);*/

            //dispatchTakePictureIntent();
            if (checkPermission(YourActivity.class))
                cameraIntent();
        }
    });
}

 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                cameraIntent();
            }

            break;
    }
}


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
public static boolean checkPermission(final Context context)
{
    int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if(currentAPIVersion>=android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
                alertBuilder.setMessage("External storage permission is necessary");
                alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                alert.show();

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

private void cameraIntent() {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile(SetupProfileActivity.this);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "IOException");
        }

        //For Android SDk 24+, 7.0
        if (photoFile != null) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                mPhotoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getPackageName() + ".provider", photoFile);

                List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(cameraIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
                for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
                    String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
                    grantUriPermission(packageName, mPhotoUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                }
            } else {
                mPhotoUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
            }

            //mPhotoUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mPhotoUri);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: createImageFile method missing.  And can not resolve READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. Also checkPermission method problem.

Comment: createImageFile method, you have already it on your original code. And add import android.Manifest; for READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: And add below code to manifest.         <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>

Comment: I added this: <uses-permission android:name="android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, no READ_STORAGE_EXTERNAL ?

Comment: minSDK version and maxSDK version which you defined?

Comment: I don't know about minSDK and maxSDK.